# IPv6 network config on virtual box running two Srv2008R2 and Win 7

Tags: ipv6

am trying to set up a test network on my windows 7 laptop to run in an IPv6 environment. basically i have downloaded virtualbox  4.3.12 latest version then created three virtual machines, two are Windows Server 2008R2 and 1 Windows 7, all are 64bit.

On one of the Windows Server 2008R2 machine, i have configured it as the AD, DHCP and DNS server and dynamically assigned a Ipv6 address of fda8:06c3:ce53:a890::1 basically following this [post](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2228461/microsoft-subnet/setting-up-dhcpv6-to-dynamically-issue-ipv6-addresses-in-a-network.html)

The second Server is has only been configured with Web server role and left the Window 7 machine as virgin install.

I have disabled ipv4 on all three machines however am unable to connect any of the machines to the test domain, the error i get is " The Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain "test.local" could not be contacted. i searched Google and unable to resolve it with all solutions

i have tried NAT, Bridged and Host-only without any success of being able to add the machines to the domain, any suggestions, did i miss something somewhere

I noticed that ipv6 is greyed out in virtualbox preferences, so is another alternative i can use to by pass this or if i can enable it.

Comment: Please don't copy&paste IPv6 ULA addresses from examples. You can generate your own ULA addresses for free! I like to use https://www.sixxs.net/tools/grh/ula/. Go there, enter your MAC address and the IPv6 ULA prefix will automatically be generated for you :)

Comment: Thank sander, i must admit, am new to ipv6 and still trying to get to grips with it. i have used the link you have provided and i will now adjust my addresses accordingly.

Comment: The reason is to avoid conflicting prefixes. With 2<sup>40</sup> (= 1099511627776) different ULA /48 prefixes available the chances are pretty small that your ULA addresses will conflict with anybody else's even when you set up VPNs to different places. Try that with RFC1918 space ;)  It does depend on everybody generating a different one though :)

Comment: I was able to add the new IP addresses however I still need help on what network adaptor to use for the AD controller, the second server and if I need to make any changes in the virtualbox preferences. do I need to use a third party application to network these three machines using ipv6

Answer (score 0):

managed to find the solution after more hours of searching, here is the error i got and solution [Join a domain when DNS name does not exist](https://web.archive.org/web/20210116213953/http://geekswithblogs.net/technetbytes/archive/2011/10/09/147233.aspx)

The issue is i have been using fd21:b305:d809::5 as the DNS server yet its fe80::9db6:a07e:717:e3bb.

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : test.local
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 1024::9db6:a07e:717:e3bb
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd21:b305:d809::5
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fda8:6c3:ce53:a899:9db6:a07e:717:e3bb
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9db6:a07e:717:e3bb%11
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fd21:b305:d809::1
```

I also configured both 2008R2 virtual servers as NAT network, now everything is working fine